# Change the Table tools pdf title name in html

Tags: javascript, html, tabletools

How to give table caption as pdf title in Table tools

as of now HTML page title is coming as pdf title.

I am generating pdf with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
            "sScrollY": 200,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "110%",
            "sSwfPath": "../mymedia/savefiles/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            }
            } )
            .columnFilter({
                aoColumns: {{columnfilters|safe}}
        });
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"sTitle"` to override with name whatever you require... something like:

```
"sTitle" : "Attribute report"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Jahnavi K` is right . we can do using `sTitle` and  You just need to dosomething like say

```
  "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "../datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [{
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sTitle": "To Pdf", // this does the trick
                    "mColumns": [1, 2, 3]
                }]
    }
```